# Placement of adverbials

Tags: adverb-position

> 1. Max prepares the tea with an electric heater  in his shop every day.
> 2. Max prepares the tea in his shop every day with an electric heater.

I am bit confused about how to use these kinds of sentence.

Comment: They are a bit ambiguous. (It should be ***prepares*** - with an ’s’ also you need some articles).  The first could be interpreted as “Max prepares the tea with the electric heater [that is] in his shop.” The second, “Max prepares the tea [that is] in his shop every day with an electric heater.”  Likely you want something like, “Max prepares tea in his shop every day using an electric heater.” If the story of the tea’s journey is being told: “Max orders the tea, Max picks up the tea. etc. You might  disambiguate further by saying. “In his shop, Max prepares the tea using an electric heater.”

Comment: i want to make sure this kind of placement as "with electric heater' it is a manner so where it should be placed at last as in second sentence or at first or either is fine

Comment: I would write 'Every day Max prepares the tea in his shop with an electric heater'.

Comment: Chris is right; three consecutive adverbials is clunky.